# How to Fix server error 500 when send a Multipart file in retorfit android

Tags: java, android, jackson, retrofit2

I am uploading files using retrofit but there is a server error when POST the file with the data

The Post man Request is working an uploading the files but when it comes to andoid it's return a server error 500
Here is where I upload the files
      [image: This is the PostMan body]

```
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("s_name", name);
    map.put("s_file_number", fileNumber);
    map.put("fk_i_extension_id", 3);
    map.put("fk_i_project_id", 1);
    map.put("s_description", description);
    map.put("fk_i_type_id", 6);
    map.put("b_secret", 1);
    map.put("fk_i_category_id", 60);
    map.put("s_file", s_file.headers());
    map.put("s_attachments", listOfFilePart);




    Call<ArchiverMainObject> fileCall = ArchiveApplication.apiRequests.addFile(token, map);
    fileCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArchiverMainObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArchiverMainObject> call, Response<ArchiverMainObject> response) {

      f (response.errorBody() != null) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject = 
         new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ArchiverMainObject> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse:  addFile  error " + t.getMessage());

        }
    });

}
```

The File converter

```
 @NonNull
 private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, String url) {

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(url);

    RequestBody requestFile = 
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), 
     requestFile);
}
```

The ClientAPi

```
 @Multipart
@POST("files/new")
Call<ArchiverMainObject> addFile(
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @PartMap Map<String, Object> newFile);
```

this is the error part of the code:

```
  {"status":{"success":false,"message":"Undefined variable: 
  fileName","status_code":500},"debug":
```

Comment: A 500 error code means the server is having issues with your request and is erroring out. As to why it is erroring out, you posted the answer in your question in that you are missing the variable `fileName` in your map in the request. That or the server is having an error with a variable it defined as `fileName`

Comment: The problem is when I POST the request on postman there is no need for fileName

Answer (score 0):

I Solve it by edit the api interface method by sperate  the mutlipart from the map

From this:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("files/new")
    Call<ArchiverMainObject> addFile(
           @Header("Authorization") String token,
           @PartMap Map<String, Object> newFile);
```

To this:

```
      @Multipart
      @POST("files/new")
     Call<ArchiverMainObject> addFile(
           @Header("Authorization") String token,
           @PartMap Map<String, Object> newFile,
           @Part MultipartBody.Part  file);
```